# Boundary Conditions for Spherical Harmonics Problem

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, boundary-conditions, spherical-harmonics

I have encountered a problem with electrostatics potentials. The problem is given as follows:

A sphere of radius $$ has the potential $\Phi(a,\theta, \phi)$ at the boundary. Obtain expressions of the exterior and interior potential.

**Solution:**
The general solution is given by:
$$\Phi(r,\theta, \phi)=\sum_{l\geq0}\sum_{m=-l}^{l}{\left(A_{lm}r^l+B_{lm}r^{-(l+1)}\right)Y_{lm}\left(\theta, \phi\right)} $$

for the outside of the sphere when $r\rightarrow \infty$ then we have $\Phi(r,\theta, \phi)\rightarrow 0$. This implies that $A_{lm}=0$ for all $l\neq0$. Thus,
$$\Phi(r,\theta, \phi)=A_{00}+\sum_{l\geq0}\sum_{m=-l}^{l}{\left(B_{lm}r^{-(l+1)}\right)Y_{lm}\left(\theta, \phi\right)} $$
At the boundary $r=a$, we must have, $\Phi(a,\theta, \phi)=V(\theta, \phi)$

$$V(\theta, \phi)=A_{00}+\sum_{l\geq0}\sum_{m=-l}^{l}{\left(B_{lm}r^{-(l+1)}\right)Y_{lm}\left(\theta, \phi\right)} $$
i.e
$$A_{00}=0$$
Therefore, we can see that,
$$A_{lm}=0, \forall l,m$$

Then the general solution drops to,
$$V(\theta, \phi)=\sum_{l\geq0}\sum_{m=-l}^{l}{\left(B_{lm}r^{-(l+1)}\right)Y_{lm}\left(\theta, \phi\right)} $$

My question is how can we get $A_{00}$ in the general solution after applying the boundary conditions and then how do we come up with $A_{lm}=0, \forall l,m$? I don't understand, how did they proceed in that steps.

Comment: @Sancol. How do we know the potential function is square integrable? Is there any specific theorem or something?

Comment: @SaaN Square integrability is not the right condition, you only want to concern yourself with the limit at infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the first boundary condition that $\Phi(r,\theta,\phi)\rightarrow 0$ as $r\rightarrow \infty$. In order for the potential to meet this condition, any terms in the general solution dependent on $r$ must be such that they do not blow up as $r$ approaches $\infty$. For example consider $\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow\infty} r^n$, as grows larger and larger the function $r^n$ grows larger even faster than $r$. It therefore stands to reason that there can be no such terms, terms that have positive powers of $r$, in the general solution of $\Phi$; thus we should set the coefficients $A_{lm}=0$, except for $A_{00}$, which is the coefficient of a term with a zeroth power of $r$ and is thus not excluded by the boundary condition at infinity. The negative powers of $r$, specifically $R^{-(l+1)}$ cause no trouble as they each go to zero in the limit that $r\rightarrow\infty$.

Now for the boundary condition at the surface of the sphere, $r=a$. Now one must make use of the fact that the general solution has spherical symmetry, as is indicated by the geometry of the conductor. Hence, when $r=a$ the solution must depend only on the angular variables so that $\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow a}\Phi(r,\theta,\phi)=\Phi(\theta,\phi)$. The only problem with our solution at this point is the constant term $A_{00}$ left over from the boundary condition at infinity. Such a constant term is useless because without loss of generality, one may choose $A_{00}=0$, since the electric field is determined by $-\nabla\Phi$. So we now have the general solution as:
$$\Phi(r,\theta,\phi)=\sum\sum B_{lm}r^{-(l+1)}Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi).$$